# Why can't I see the FBX version to which I want to export to?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, export, .fbx

I am trying to convert my .ply file into a an fbx file (I want to eventually do something which involves exporting the texture along with the mesh). I am following steps mentioned by another user who had the same requirement from here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1343037/blender-278-unity-55-the-correct-way-to-retain-mat.html?childToView=1627960#comment-1627960

However, the first step is to ensure that I convert with "FBX 7.4 Binary selected" - an option which I am unable to find in my window. Is this a change in UI or do I have to enable something else?

[image: On File -> Export -> FBX(.fbx)]

Thank you!

Details:

Blender Version 2.79.7

Pics on interface details (after clicking on buttons near Operator Presets):
[image]
[image]

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? The should be a dropdown to select a version between the operator preset and toggle button in Blender 2.79b.

Comment: Blender version 2.79.7  Dropdown seems to have no "version". Added pics to question, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Blender 2.79b**

Blender 2.79.7 didn't have this feature. You need to update to a more recent version of Blender. A more recent version can be installed along-side your current Blender version. The UI option for the export in 2.79b is depicted in the following image:

[image: Export options 2.79b]

---

**Blender 2.8x**

Blender 2.80 and later only support the FBX 7.x binary format. The FBX ASCII format was removed in commit [7f50cbf2b6bf0675e4a178cbb19aca90f39bd374](https://developer.blender.org/rBA7f50cbf2b6bf0675e4a178cbb19aca90f39bd374). Exporter options can be found in the sidebar of the file browser. In case they aren't displayed by default,  click on the gear icon to toggle the visibility of the sidebar.

[image: Exporter options in file browser]

Comment: Any updates on this for version 2.82? I likewise don't see this option whenever I open up the export menu.

Comment: @JoshWhitlow Sure, I'll post an update. The settings for the exporter can be viewed by clicking on the gear icon in the file browser.

Comment: I found the answer, the ASCII export method was removed in 2.8: [2.8: Remove ASCII FBX 6.1 exporter](https://developer.blender.org/T53877)